# Select first empty cell in specific column when switching between worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, cells

I have a single workbook with multiple sheets. Sheet 1 uses cell A1 as a search box to find a specific sheet in the book. The sheets after Sheet 1 are named like this, SO123456 with different numbers following the SO. I have the following code on sheet 1 to open the corresponding sheet from the value typed into A1 of Sheet 1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Sheets(Target.Value).Activate
End Sub
```

When the corresponding sheet is opened, I want to open it to the next empty cell in column A. I have some code on the SOxxxxxx sheets that populates time in Column C when my data is entered in Column A. Here is that code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Columns("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
         Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = Now
End If

End Sub
```

I'm not sure how to make sure the first empty cell in Column A is selected or where the code goes; sheet being opened or where the call is to open the sheet. I tried entering the following code below the Worksheet_Change block with no luck:

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Offset(1).Row
Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).Offset(1).Row
UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

I know next to nothing about VBA if you haven't already noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address <> "A$1” Then Exit Sub
    With WorkSheets(Target.Value)
         .Activate
         .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).Offset(1).Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you to the first empty cell in Column A

```
rowEmpty = Range("A" & 10000).End(xlup).Row +1
```

You can replace the number 10000 with a sufficiently large number that ensures there will be no data there. There are alternatives to that, but I think this one is easier to begin with.

Comment: I must mention, this method assumes that there are no empty cells in in between the first and last occupied row.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm assuming "rowEmpty" is a variable. So this would give me the next available row but how do I have the first cell selected when the sheet is selected?

Comment: Yes rowEmtpy is an integer variable. To get the first empty cell use
`rowEmpty = ActiveWorksheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row +1` . Select by using `ActiveWorksheet.Range("A" & rowEmpty).Select`

Answer (score 0):

With this code, typing a sheet name in cell A1 from sheet1 will activate the sheet you type, and the active cell will be the first one in blank in column A.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Sheets(Target.Value).Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(Sheets(Target.Value).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1, 1).Select
End Sub
```